# WCF Data Services and Projections. How to get the entity URI from an entity projection instance?

Tags: .net-4.0, wcf-data-services, astoria

I'm using DataServiceContext to load some entity projections (entities have many properties, to minimize traffic I load only those properties, which are needed at the moment) like this:

```
from x in ctx.Portfolios
       select new 
       {
         Id = x.Id,
         Name = x.Name,
         PortfolioName = x.PortfolioName,
         Description = x.Description,
         ValidFrom = x.ValidFrom,
         ValidUntil = x.ValidUntil
       };
```

What I need is a valid URI of the entity to load it for details view.

I've tried to use ctx.TryGetUri(obj, out uri), but it always returns null (probably because of the non-tracking projections, however, I've loaded the PK property (Id), so it must not be the case).

The question is, how do I determine the URI of the underlying data entity, having a projection object with PK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# anonymous types are generated with non-settable properties (the properties don't have setters). As a result WCF Data Services client can't track those (since it would not make any sense, it could not overwrite the property value during materialization). So the result is that the instance is not tracked.
To workaround this just declare a non-anonymous class with the properties you need and project into that (make sure the properties are settable).
Note that VB's anonymous types do have settable properties, so they will get tracked.

Comment: I don't need to set loaded properties. I just need to get proper URI of the entity to load its full version (not projection) in other data context for editing.

Comment: If you're only interested in the URI, then don't project anything, simply select the entire entity and then use DataServiceContext.GetEntityDescriptor() to get the descriptor of the entity in which you can find the SelfLink and EditLink properties which store the URI pointing to that entity (first one for reading, second one for editting).

Comment: I need projections to load lightweight list of by business entities to show on UI. When user double click selected projection, then I need to load a full (200 column) entity.

Comment: Then the easiest way is to declare a class which only contains a couple of the properties of the given entity and use that in your projection. But if you're in C# you have to define that class by hand and make the properties settable.